# Animation-delay function not working on text (opacity)

Tags: html, css, web, animation, delay

I'm trying to make an animation-delay on my animation. The animation is used on some text, and the animation-delay line doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code :

```
.wtitle {
opacity:100%;
animation-name: afade;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-delay: 15s;
}

@keyframes afade {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:100%;
}
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`animation-fill-mode: both;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Without this line, your animation will only have any effect when it is actually running. That means at the 15 seconds delay, the animation has no effect on the `.htitle` whatsoever.

```css
.wtitle {
opacity:100%;
animation-name: afade;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes afade {
from {
    opacity:0;
}
to {
    opacity:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wtitle">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wtitle {
  opacity: 100%;
  background: red;
  animation-name: afade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

You are missing 1 attribute.